# Why does Binding within a CellTemplate not work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection called "MaterialList" to a Combobox placed in a column.
**C#**

```
public class Delivery
{
//Some other Properties which work
...
public ObservableCollection<string> MaterialList { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<OpenPosition> OpenPositions { get; set; }

public Delivery()
{
  this.MaterialList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  this.OpenPositions = new ObservableCollection<OpenPosition>();
}
}
```

I've checked if there is data in that list, and there is!
**XAML:**

```
                    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid4" MaxHeight="2000" AutoGenerateColumns="None" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDelivery.OpenPositions}">     
                            <dxg:GridColumn" Header="{Binding LanguageTexts[_MaterialNumber]}">
                                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDelivery.MaterialList}" SelectedIndex="0" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

My ComboBox doesn't display anything. I am guessing there is something wrong because I have use the DataContext from the Itemssource.
Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the Binding as `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SelectedDelivery.MaterialList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestoryType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"`.

The issue is like you think, the datacontext for the combobox is taken from `SelectedDelivery.OpenPositions` and the way I suggested is using the DataContext of the view, rather than that from the ItemsSource.

Hope it helps!